# MS Access Compile Error opening excel application

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to write a simple onclick button to open an excel file that already exists on my desktop

what i dont understand is I am using the same Dim as many other examples I have seen. but I am getting a Compile Error "User defined type not defined" and it pulls up the code showing blue highlights Dim excelapp As Excel.Application but Yellow highlight on Private Sub line. Where am i going wrong. is the failure actually further down the code? I ma running Access 365 and Should i be using a different syntax to reference Excel?

```
Private Sub cmdcopyfieldsonly_Click()
Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
Dim wbTarget As Excel.Workbooks
Dim qdfquerytest As QueryDef
Dim rsquerytest As Recordset
Set qdfquerytest = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("OpenComplaintsQuery")
Set rsquerytest = qdfquerytest.OpenRecordset()
Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excelapp.Visible = True
Set wbTarget = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\copytest.xlsx")
wbTarget.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value = rsquerytest(2).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to Excel? VBE >>Tools >> References.

Comment: *face palm* i cant believe i forgot about that. Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object lIbrary correct?

Comment: You can simply change `Dim excelapp As Object` and `Dim wbTarget As Object` and you don't need to add a reference. You will also need to change `Set wbTarget = Excel.Workbooks.Open("...")` as `Excel` is not defined anywhere, it needs to be `excelapp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of early vs late binding, which are mixed in your code.

- Early Binding.

Early binding requires a hard reference of the type e.g. Excel, so VBA has information about the type during compilation. You can then declare the variable by its type and also have intellisense while typing.

```
Dim app As Excel.Application
Set app = New Excel.Application
```

The drawback is when changing office versions as the code still references the old version - the reference will need to be updated.

- Late Binding

Late binding does not require a hard reference since the variable is declared using the base type of `Object` and gets resolved at runtime. No issues when changing office version but you lose intellisense.

```
Dim app As Object
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

---

In you case, this is absolutely valid when using late binding:

```
With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With .Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\copytest.xlsx")
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value = rsquerytest(2).Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Kostas, Thank you for your answer. since obviously this code was a form of testing. Do you know can the code you referenced for late binding also be used in conjunction to Merge and \ unmerging of cell ranges before or after the data is placed? or should i be looking for an alternative method to copy the data over?

Comment: for example I use "Workbooks("AACT CM Report_Rev1.xlsm").Worksheets("Report").Range("E6:H6").Merge" to merge the range of a template excel file we use for reports this is from another macro excel book we have thats old. is this doable in the Access vba?

Comment: Yes it is. As in you example, you only need to get a reference to the worksheet for the merge operation. How you get the reference to it (early or late binding) doesn't matter. In essence you should end up with this line: `wbTarget.Range("E6:H6").Merge` where `wbTarget` is the reports worksheet.

Comment: I'd say start with early binding so you can see and learn the object model (properties, subs, functions etc) through intellisense and as you gain experience, move to late binding.